# Countdown adds one hour between April and October

Tags: java, date, time, countdown

I'm working on simple countdown app to tell me how long until certain GMT time.

example:

input: 01-05-2021-02-00-00

output: (if entered time is local) 72 days, 15 hours, 21 mins, 49 secs

output(if entered time is gmt): 72 days, 17 hours, 21 mins, 33 secs

...there should be 16 not 17 hours i believe.

Everything's working fine untill input is between 1. April and 31 October. I give it GMT time and it transforms it to my local (berlin +1) time. If entered time is from mentioned interval it shows +2 hours differencer between berlin and GMT. since it is like this only for certain period of year (any year) it looks weird I don't know what went wrong?

my code:

```
String result = "";
        
        
        String date = input;
        
        SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
        Date target_date = null;
        try {
            target_date = date_format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          result += e.getMessage(); 
        }
        
        Date now = new Date();      
        
        long secs = 0;
        if(local_time_radio_btn.isSelected()) {
            secs = (target_date.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 1000;
        }else {
            int offset = target_date.getTimezoneOffset();
            long n = 1000 * offset * 60;
            long gmt = target_date.getTime() -n;
            long now_gmt = now.getTime();           
            secs = (gmt - now_gmt) / 1000;
        }
        
        long days = secs / (60*60*24);
        secs = secs % (60*60*24);
        long hours = secs / (60*60);    
        secs = secs % (60*60);
        long mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;

        result += days+" days, "+hours+" hours, "+mins+" mins, "+secs +" secs";
```

Comment: No, it's not strange to edit posts. That's one of the key features of StackOverflow--that anyone can improve posts. My contribution was to make your post more readable, and in line with site guidelines.

Comment: If you think wikis are creepy, then you may want to consider avoiding StackOverflow and Wikipedia.

Comment: @Flimzy ill definitely think abt it

Comment: Obvious question: Have you accounted for daylight savings (if it applies) ? And since I'm commenting: the edits are fine and not out of the norm.

Comment: @John3136 thanks! :) i'll check that out, sounds like it could be it ...but what about authenticity/individuality/beauty of not everything being same and mainly avoiding norms :D

Comment: Two recommendations: (1) Don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). (2) Don’t do time math yourself. Leave it to java.time for clearer code that has a greater chance of also being correct.

Comment: Thanks for adding code. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I strongly recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu-HH-mm-ss");
    
    String input = "01-05-2021-02-00-00";

    LocalDateTime targetLdt = LocalDateTime.parse(input, formatter);

    // German time case
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");

    ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
    ZonedDateTime target = targetLdt.atZone(zone);
    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(now, target);
    ZonedDateTime afterDays = now.plusDays(days);
    Duration timeDiff = Duration.between(afterDays, target);
    
    String result = days + " days, " + timeDiff.toHours() + " hours, "
            + timeDiff.toMinutesPart() + " mins, "
            + timeDiff.toSecondsPart() + " secs";
    
    System.out.println(result);
```

When I ran the code just now (2021-02-18T17:23:35.47 in Berlin), the output was:

> 71 days, 8 hours, 36 mins, 24 secs

For the UTC (or GMT) case you only need to change one line:

```
    // GMT case
    ZoneId zone = ZoneOffset.UTC;
```

> 71 days, 9 hours, 36 mins, 24 secs

### What went wrong in your code?

First, don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` as they are poorly designed and long outdated. Even if you insisted on using `Date`, you should definitely stay away from its `getTimezoneOffset` method. It has been deprecated since 1997 because it works unreliably across time zones.

Why your code gives an incorrect result in the months you mention is that it counts a day as always 24 hours. On March 28 the EU will transit to summer time (DST), so that day is only 23 hours long, giving rise to an error of exactly 1 hour. On October 31 this year the opposite transisiton may happen (I don’t think it’s been decided yet, but Java thinks that it does), so that day is 25 hours, balancing out for dates after that. Until summer time next year.

Which leads to the next point: don’t do time math yourself. It’s so easy to get wrong. And even when you get it right, it’s hard for the reader to convince oneself that it’s right. You have got a reliable date and time library that is happy to do it for you.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

What's weird about your code is that you're first parsing the input string according to a `SimpleDateFormat` instance that's configured to use local timezone (so, the resulting Date is wrong if the input was meant to be UTC), and then put a lot of effort into re-adjusting the point in time to UTC if that's what the user requested.

Instead, it would be clearer and more robust to have two `SimpleDateFormat` instances, one with the local timezone, and one with UTC, like:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
dateFormatUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

and select the correct one already when parsing.

By the way, your re-adjusting code uses deprecated features of the `Date` class, like `getTimezoneOffset()`, something that should be avoided since Java 1.1.

Comment: thanks. i've changed it, probably looks better but there still is two hours difference

Comment: its daylight saving time ...therefore it should be 2 h diff....alls good :)

Comment: @vuktctgck Judging by your comment, it seems you have solved your issue. If this answer (or any others) helped you, consider [voting on and/or accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). :)

Comment: Well, saying "it would be more robust" and then sticking to `SimpleDateFormat` is peculiar to me.